# All queries go into "Waiting for table" state on an Amazon RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We currently have following problem that caused our application to go down. All queries we do go into a "waiting for table" state and stay there, causing the MySQL servers connections to be used up.

We investigated the Issue and learned what it means, according to the MySQL manual

> Waiting for tables, Waiting for table
>
> The thread got a notification that the underlying structure for a
>   table has changed and it needs to reopen the table to get the new
>   structure. However, to reopen the table, it must wait until all other
>   threads have closed the table in question.
>
> This notification takes place if another thread has used FLUSH TABLES
>   or one of the following statements on the table in question: FLUSH
>   TABLES tbl_name, ALTER TABLE, RENAME TABLE, REPAIR TABLE, ANALYZE
>   TABLE, or OPTIMIZE TABLE.

I inspected our running processes with SHOW PROCESSLIST and found no Data Definition Language statements, or any statements that where in the list above.

What else could cause this?

Comment: What about replication threads?

Comment: Our Sysadmin said that replication does not have anything to do with it, because it is just a rotating logfile (but I might ask him again). We might use it as a backup, but currently it will fail as soon as you try to write to it, so no avail...
We are currently trying to export the data to another Instance outside of RDS but this might take a while ... 
But thanks for your help Tom :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did not really find an answer to what caused the problem, but it seems like the automatic backup feature of amazon was the culprit. We are now up and running again after contacting Amazon support.

Comment: Indeed, most backup methods require a brief table flush to make sure the state of the data is consistent at the point where the backup process begins. On a busy system with frequent backup snapshots, you are going to notice it manifesting like this. Typical way around it is to have an asynchronous replica that you use for backups instead of backing up the master server.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today. At last, I found it is caused by the concurrency of a big query and the backup process. Mysqldump with –master-data may cause flush table command.
See this
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35157.

My situation is:
The flush command was waiting for the big query;
Other querys were waiting for the flush table command became completed, so they were blocked.
When the big query completed, things went right.

So I guess you might have a big query at that time.